# Sitecore Upgrade Exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I upgraded from Sitecore 7.0 initial release to Sitecore 7.1
when I run the update package the below error appears

> Exception details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. at
>   Sitecore.Update.UpdateHelper.GetHistoryFolderName(String historyPath)
>   at Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.SetHistoryPath(String
>   historyPath) at
>   Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.InstallPackage(MetadataView view)
>   at Sitecore.Update.InstallUpdatePackage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

The following is a screen shot for the error:

[image]

Comment: I would contact Sitecore Support as the error suggests. And/or try again...

Comment: Do you have WFFM installed or other modules? Updating to 7 to 7.1 you need also to update WFFM from version 2.3 to 2.4

Comment: Check if the permissions are correct on the folders, also try to see if you have the history folder Website\temp\__UpgradeHistory

Comment: Check that you have upgraded Sitecore Upgrade Installation wizard before running of  update.

Comment: thanks all there error appears because I miss run the  CM script when I upgrade from 6.5 to 6.6 but the show when I upgraded from 7.0 to 7.1